# jQuery isotope for filtering NOT working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

i'm working on a website, and now stuck on jQuery isotope, i need some help here, please
i'm using jquery isotope to filter div, but somehow it doesn't work

My HTML:

```
<center><a href="" class="filter" rel="all">show all</a> | <a href="" class="filter" rel="green">green</a> | <a href="" class="filter" rel="blue">blue</a> | <a href="" class="filter" rel="pink">pink</a></center>
<br>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box pink"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box pink"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box pink"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.wrap{
    margin: auto;
    width: 660px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
.box{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
.blue{
    background: blue;
}
.pink{
    background: pink;
}
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrap').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.box'
    });

    $('a.filter').click(function() {
        var to_filter = $(this).attr('rel');
        if(to_filter == 'all') {
            $('.box').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.box').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass(to_filter)) {
                    $(this).fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

or you can view this link : http://jsfiddle.net/wPdXF/

**My Exact Problem:**
after i click filter link, the divs doesn't shuffle/animate

can anyone help me please ?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: In your JSFiddle it works as expected?

Comment: @reinder : no, absolutely not.......thank you for answering :D

Comment: Then you need to explain the problem better. If I open your jsfiddle and I press "green" it shows me only green boxes. Same for all other colors and "show all" shows me all boxes. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: jQuery Isotope is designed to be responsive, so when you click the filter buttons, an animation should play, and the boxes should move to inline floats as screen space allows.  That's what he means.  OP, I'll take a look at it, I have used isotope a few times.

Comment: @reindeer: my problem is, after i click color filter menu, the divs doesn't shuffle/animate, it's still has gaps

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch : thank you :D that's what i mean...sorry my english is terrible

Comment: Please don't add [Solved] to the question title or edit your solution into the question. If you think your solution is useful post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're running into (where it "filters" items, but doesn't reposition them, or animate the repositioning) is because you're using jquery's built in hide/show instead of isotope's built in filtering mechanism.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wrap').isotope();

$('a.filter').click(function() {
    var to_filter = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(to_filter == 'all') {
        $('.wrap').isotope({filter: '.box'});
    } else {
        $('.wrap').isotope({filter: '.'+to_filter});
    }

});
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yDPxK/1/

What you need to do is provide isotope with the filter (the class names that you're matching from your `rel` attribute.  using jquery's default fadeIn/fadeOut will just change their display property value, not alter their position in the DOM.

Filtering documentation: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html

Comment: i'm already using filter option, but it's NO luck...still no animation/shuffle

Comment: alright, i'll fork your fiddle and see if i can get it to work.  Are you using one of the custom layout modes?  Masonry or centered are the most popular.

Comment: I added a link in my answer to a working example.  You'll have to play with a layout to get the cooler animation options.  Good luck!

Comment: many thanks for your answer...BUT, it's still has NO animation like in this demo : [http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html)...any solutions ?

Comment: ohh...my BAD, now it's done !!!, thank you.....just add some CSS3 animation and it's works like magic...thank you